# How do I switch "time left" between chapter and book in the iOS Kindle App?

Tags: kindle-app

When I read books in the iOS Kindle App, there is an indicator on the bottom that says how much time is left in the book based upon my reading speed.

How can I change this indicator to show the time left in the chapter instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tap on the indicator to cycle through the options. For me (using Kindle for iPad version 4.4) it cycles through

1. Loc X of Y
2. X mins left in book
3. X minutes left in chapter
4. blank